# Deploying Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, deploying

When deploying Windows Phone 7 application i have choice for References Properties - Copy Local. Do I have Copy Local such references as System.XML, System.XML.Linq, Microsoft.Phone.Controls?

How to prepare my app for marketplace? For example I am using Release instead of Debug Configuration in Visual Studio. What else is important (I had Certification failure twice - once my app terminated at launch as reviewer said, 2nd time i included all rerefences as copy local and had problems with Microsoft.Phone.dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you wouldn't need to set anything on your References they are handled automatically by Visual Studio. My references Copy Local property is set to false.

The first Certification error you got was because your application exited without a warning, you should catch every exception and inform the user about them and then you can exit the application if you can't handle the error.

You should read this MSDN resource thoroughly, it is important.

[Application Certification Requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

The Most important parts are :

[Application policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Content Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184842%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Application Submission Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184844%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Technical Certification Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Additional Requirements for Specific Application Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184838%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

And before you send your app you have an additional option to test your app yourself with Visual Studio build in Marketplace Test Kit found in the project menu.

Comment: Thanks for resources. I have tested my application with Marketplace Test Kit tool and where was no errors. It's hard to understand where i can have exceptions as my application is very simple. I am don't have windows phone 7 device but in emulator I don't have any terminations or something. Then i have tested my app on device couple weeks ago there was also no errors.

Comment: Interesting, and what did the tester write in the error report the first time?